# Which type operator?

Tags: scala

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

trait Foo {
  val begin: Int
}

object Test {
  def beginIndex[T <: Vector[Foo]](data: T): ListMap[Int, T] = {
    data.foldLeft(ListMap[Int, T]())({case (map, e) => map + ((e.begin, (map(e.begin) :+ e)))})
}
```

gives me the error

```
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Foo]
required: T
```

I assume `<:` is the incorrect type operator, but I'm not sure which
one would be the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the proper type operator, however, since you're using the scala collections api you need to provide a builder for collections of type `T` otherwise scala will default to using the `Vector` builder which can only give you back a `Vector` not a `T`. You can get this to compile if you add a requirement for an implicit `T` builder:

```
def beginIndex[T <: Vector[Foo]](data: T)(implicit bf : CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Foo], Foo, T]): ListMap[Int, T] = {
  data.foldLeft(ListMap[Int, T]())({case (map, e) => map + ((e.begin, (map(e.begin) :+ e)))})
}
```

If you're using a scala collection that inherits from `Vector` then you might be in luck as it probably already has an imnplicit builder, though I'm not sure you can get the types to work out, but `Vector` should work. As a side note, I don't think you're function can ever work properly as `map(e.begin)` will always try to get a value out of an empty map and throw an exception.

```
  println(Test.beginIndex(Vector(new Foo {
    override val begin: Int = 0
  })))

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 0
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
```